# Displaying box divs inline with text under them

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 images i want to display them inline style with text under them but without using bootstrap grid-system because i want them to be close to each other and centered, i tried doing it but once i add the text they get displayed under each other, how can i fix that? here is my code:

```css
.box{
display:inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
<div class="box">
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" style="height:120px">
<p>Test</p>
</div>
<div class="box">
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" style="height:120px">
<p>Test</p>
</div>
<div class="box">
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" style="height:120px">
<p>Test</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)** to the rescue (along with proper HTML semantics and no inline CSS styles)!

```css
.container { display:flex; justify-content:center; }
.container figure { text-align:center; margin:0; }
.container img { height:120px; }
```

```html
<div class="text-center container">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    <figcaption>Test</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    <figcaption>Test</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    <figcaption>Test</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: this is perfect thank you except that i cant bring them to the center of my page do you have any idea why?

Comment: You want it so there is no space between the boxes? Yes, hold on a sec and I'll update the answer.

Comment: yes please i want them centered to the page with no spaces

Answer (score 2):

You were close, but it should be `display: inline-block`. See code snippet:

```css
.box{
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
<div class="box">
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" style="height:120px">
<p>Test</p>
</div>
<div class="box">
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" style="height:120px">
<p>Test</p>
</div>
<div class="box">
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" style="height:120px">
<p>Test</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Note: I see you've added the `text-center` class which is not working here on Stack Overflow, but should do the trick in your own code.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `flex` on the parent and it will put them side-by-side.

```css
.boxes{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="text-center boxes">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" style="height:120px">
    <p>Test</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" style="height:120px">
    <p>Test</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" style="height:120px">
    <p>Test</p>
  </div>
</div>
```